# JSP Error: The method is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: function, jsp, syntax-error

I have a function in JSP and when I call it I get an error and I don't really know the reason. The function code works without problems if I just paste it where I need it.

> The method console_table(PrintWriter, int, String[]) in the type console_jsp is not applicable for the arguments (JspWriter, int, String[])

JSP Function

```
<%!
public void console_table (java.io.PrintWriter out, int stackNr, String [] pstackNr) {
int c=0;
for(int i=0;i<stackNr;i++) {
    out.println("<h3>Stiva "+(i+1)+"</h3>");
    out.println("<div id='content_wrap'>");
    for(int j=0;j<Integer.parseInt(pstackNr[i]);j++){

        out.println("<div id='structure'>");
        out.println("<div class='stack'>");
        out.println("<table border='1'>");
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td><div id='empty"+c+"' class='empty'></div></td>");
        out.println("<td><div id='empty"+c+"' class='empty'></div></td>");
        out.println("<td><div id='empty"+c+"' class='empty'></div></td>");
        out.println("<td><div id='empty"+c+"' class='empty'></div></td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("</div>");
        out.println("</div>");
        c++;
    }
    out.println("</div>");
}
}
%>
```

File Import

```
<%@ include file="src/libs/console.lib.jsp" %>
```

Call Function

```
<% 
int stackNr = 3;
String [] pstackNr = db_pstackNr.split(",");
console_table (out, stackNr, pstackNr); 
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
public void console_table (java.io.PrintWriter out, int stackNr, String [] pstackNr)
```

to

```
public void console_table (javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter out, int stackNr, String [] pstackNr) throws java.io.IOException
```

and

change

```
console_table (out, stackNr, pstackNr); 

try {
    console_table (out, stackNr, pstackNr); 
} catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    //handle the exception
}
```

should make it work. Basically, the problem is that 'out' is an instance of JspWriter, and it's not compatible with PrintWriter. (If JspWriter were the subclass of PrintWriter, it would have been fine, however, they are both direct subclasses of java.io.Writer)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter.html

Comment: hmmm... now is throwing me another error with that change
**Unhandled exception type IOException**

Comment: **public void console_table (javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter out, int stackNr, String [] pstackNr) throws java.io.IOException**
and now is working. Thank you

Comment: oh.. you already changed it while I was searching the right solution :D

Comment: Yes JspWriter's println() method throws checked exception, so you need to rethrow it or try-catch it